# Debugging a Ruby program on a MS Visual Studio Code editor on Windows 10 or greater platform

Tags: ruby

I'm using a Windows 10 computer with MS Visual Studio Code and I'm trying to debug simple ruby code using the available extensions. There used to be Ruby Lang support and debug by Peng Lv but it is depricated. I am also using version of Ruby that is greater than 3.2.x.

They claim that Ruby LSP extension is a replacement but it sure is not working like a regular debugger add on. Anyone has tried recently to use MS Studio Code with Ruby and debug?  How do you do it (like which extensions do you recommend)? what is the basic steps to enable? I tried the recommended launch.json from the Ruby LSP extension description and it does not work for me for some reason.

Thanks in advance.